# What is the general approach to create FIPS compliant SSH?

Tags: linux, openssh, fips

Please bear in mind that I have **no cyber-security background at all**, but have been tasked by my company with making certain applications on our platform FIPS-compliant.

From what I've discussed with my co-workers, our platform requires a FIPS-compliant SSH.

We have a FIPS-compliant OpenSSL (well, a version of OpenSSL configured and compiled against the fipscanister object at least). From here, how can I create a FIPS-compliant OpenSSH?

**Note:**

Our target OS is a derivative of Linux.

I've found some patches that looked promising, like [this one](https://github.com/Hubbitus/rpm-openssh-epel-include), but they either lack documentation, or ([in the above case](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/hubbitus/epel-openssh-include/)) flat out say this is for the author's use only and everyone else should steer clear.

I think a good answer would be something like:

- "When you configure OpenSSH, enable/disable *these* algorithms" or...
- "Download source for OpenSSH version X and patch it with *this* patch"

Comment: Just a note, but you should probably hire someone who actually _has_ a background in information security when you are ensuring FIPS-compliance. Otherwise you are opening yourself up to liabilities.

Comment: What are your requirements exactly? There's a world of difference between using software that's undergone a FIPS certification (expensive, and because you can't do security updates, it's very insecure), and using only NIST-approved algorithms (which is the default with many programs anyway).

Comment: Let's go with that second one. We're probably going to get our stuff certified at the end, so that seems like the logical first step.

Comment: You should approach a FIPS lab with this question, as there are many nuances that impossible to cover in a comment. Brief answer - FIPS 140-2 or CMVP certificate applies to cryptographic module. If you need (and I doubt you do) FIPS certified SSH, then CMVP certificate must have crypto primitives and SSH (SSH CVL) protocol included in the scope of certificate. Vanilla OpenSSL does not include any protocols in the scope of OpenSSL's CMVP certificate, but some distros like RHEL have OS-wide CMVP certificates that include protocols.

Answer (score 2):

Your target is, as you wrote, a derivative of Linux. Several Linux distributions manage *crypto-policies* centrally, and **FIPS** is one of the choices. With `update-crypto-policies --set FIPS` the sshd is, in effect, reconfigured using an environment variable sourced from a file: `/usr/share/crypto-policies/FIPS/opensshserver.txt` (This example is from AlmaLinux 8.8.)

You can **further restrict** compliance to **FIPS and Open Criteria** with: `update-crypto-policies --set FIPS:OSPP`. This means you can only use a subset of possible encryption ciphers and key exchange protocols, etc. Please note that FIPS is a compliance standard for the U.S.A. FIPS = Federal Information Processing Standard. The DISA-STIG benchmark mandates FIPS, and there are several audit tools that can help assess compliance, for example [open-scap](https://static.open-scap.org/ssg-guides/ssg-rhel8-guide-stig_gui.html#xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_sshd_use_approved_kex_ordered_stig).

Run the openssh server with these options to have the same subset active, and the rest disabled:

```
-oCiphers=aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc \
-oMACs=hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-512 \
-oGSSAPIKeyExchange=no \
-oKexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512 \
-oHostKeyAlgorithms=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com \
-oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com \
-oCASignatureAlgorithms=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512
```